# flot tooltip on imaginary vertical line

Tags: jquery, tooltip, flot

How can I add the ability for a tooltip for a point to show when the 
mouse "hovers" over that point OR any pixel on an imaginary vertical line above/below that point?

My graph only has 1 line on it. I 
would like it so a tooltip can show for the datapoint when the mouse 
goes over an "invisible" vertical line through the point - not forcing 
the user to explicitly hover over the point.

I found this solution - but it seems like a hack (and doesn't work): 
[Flot mousehover algorithm to detect purely based on x location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498321/flot-mousehover-algorithm-to-detect-purely-based-on-x-location)

Is there any better way to do this short of hacking the source?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about (its bigcharts, but this 
is the function I want).  You can hover over the line or hover over 
any point on the X axis to show the point that is on that X axis 
pixel: 
[http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=^DJI+Interactive#chart1:symbol=^dji;range=1d;indicator=volume;charttype=line ;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5EDJI%20Interactive#chart1:symbol=%5Edji;range=1d;indicator=volume;charttype=line%20;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined)

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax

Comment: ^ yep looking for that - but in Flot

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar to the Yahoo chart in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/bVrrE/36/). I just update the x position whenever the mouse is hovering:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    latestPosition = pos;
    if (!updateTooltipTimeout) {
        updateTooltipTimeout = setTimeout(update, 30);
    }
});
```

then run the update method. The update method (taken from the [flot crosshairs](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html) example) interpolates the y datapoint closest to x, then displays a tooltip and point on the line:

```
function update() {
    updateTooltipTimeout = null;
    var pos = latestPosition;

    var i, j, dataset = plot.getData();
    for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; ++i) {
        var series = dataset[i];

        // Find the nearest points, x-wise
        for (j = 0; j < series.data.length; ++j) {
            if (series.data[j][0] > pos.x) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Now Interpolate
        var y,
        p1 = series.data[j - 1],
            p2 = series.data[j];

        if (p1 == null) {
            y = p2[1];
        } else if (p2 == null) {
            y = p1[1];
        } else {
            y = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * (pos.x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]);
        }

        var o = plot.pointOffset({
            x: pos.x,
            y: y
        });

        updateTooltip(o.left, o.top,
            "x: " + pos.x.toFixed(2) + " y: " + y.toFixed(2));

        plotPoint(o.left, o.top, 5, "rgb(153,180,125)", "circle");
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that in order to actually interact with the datapoints, you will have to alter the source.

Comment: This is close - however I'm looking for only displaying info about points on the line. I've updated the question to be more clear.